# How to fadeIn div with appended HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

http://jsfiddle.net/leonwho/65bsS/25/

I have 2 buttons, clicking either should fade them both out(their container), and then appends the `deleteXhtml` variable to the `.delete_x_here` hidden div and fade in the delete button.

This seems like it should be straight forward, perhaps my DOM traversing is messed up?

I notice this in the Chrome console:

[image]

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="incoming-actions">

        <div class="delete_x_here"></div>

        <div class="button_td">
            <div id="choice-accept-request" class="request-btn quick-accept"></div>
            <div id="choice-deny-request" class="request-btn quick-deny"></div>
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

jQuery

```
$('.request-btn').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var btnArea = $(this).closest('.incoming-actions');
    var btnAccept = $(this).closest('.incoming-actions #choice-accept-request');
    var btnDeny = $(this).closest('.incoming-actions #choice-deny-request');
    var deleteBox = $(this).closest(".incoming-actions .delete_x_here");
    var deleteXhtml = $('<div id="btn-delete-request" class="delete-x" title="Delete">X</div>');
    var btnBox = $(this).closest('.button_td');
    var user_choice = $(this).attr('id');

    if (user_choice === 'choice-accept-request') {

        console.log('choice-accept-request');

        // Disable Buttons here while waiting on Request
        $(btnAccept).css('cursor','auto');
        $(btnAccept).attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $(btnDeny).css('cursor','auto');
        $(btnDeny).attr("disabled", "disabled");

        //change buttons here
        $(btnBox).fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(deleteXhtml).appendTo(deleteBox);
            $(deleteBox).fadeIn('fast');
            console.log('fade in delete button with appended deleteXhtml here');
        });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that deleteBox is not defined.

Use this to define it correctly:

`var deleteBox = $(this).parents(".incoming-actions").find(".delete_x_here");`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65bsS/28/)

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to fadeIn it needs to be hidden first. So this could work.

```
$(deleteXhtml).appendTo(deleteBox).hide().fadeIn(1200);
```

Comment: Ah yeah that was a mistake, but actually in my real code I already have it hidden. I think the problem is that for some reason deleteBox ends up being `[]` jQuery isn't finding my .delete_x_here div, or for that matter my deny button div either :(